# Wiki stack/package overview

Tags: ros, stack, documentation, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upload many documentation for a project. But i have one problem.
Hi,
I also want have the overview of the packages in the wiki with are cohere with each other.

Because my bad english one example.
At the navigation documentation you have under the distribution line a stack of packages: navigation: amcl | base_local_planner | ...

how can I activate this function?

I have already a Metapackage and have indexed all my packages at rosdistro.

Thankyou

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266022/wiki-stack/package-overview/) by [FelixMarek](https://answers.ros.org/users/31109/felixmarek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have already a Metapackage and have indexed all my packages at rosdistro.

if you have already done that -- and all the jobs for it have run -- then you should get the additional links under the version rocker automatically.

Just make sure you have all your packages listed as `run_depend`s (manifest v1) or `exec_depend`s (manifest v2) of your metapackage.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0